# Was starkiller base a rogue planet?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, planets

Was Starkiller Base a rogue planet, wandering through the galaxy/universe?

The planet could be similar to Zonama Sekot,( a sentient world born
from the homeworld of the Yuuzhan Vong, and capable of hyperspace travel.)

Comment: I dunno, seemed like it was a Wizard, if any class. OP attack that needs preparation. Weak to ranged once its arcane shields drop.

Comment: What does that comment mean?  Zonama Sekot is a reference to "Star Wars Legends", and the "New Jedi Order" series.

Comment: Sorry, just goofing off. "Rogue" is a class in Dungeon and Dragons, as are Wizards.

Comment: @CreationEdge I lol'd

Comment: It had forests, if I remember rightly, so it could hardly be the normal sort of rogue planet.  And if it was sentient I don't think it would have been very keen on having its insides torn out and replaced with the weapon.  That's gotta hurt.

Comment: if so, how did it ever have time enough with a sun to evolve & grow forests?

Comment: [Which planet became Starkiller Base?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/111570/21267)

Answer (score 3):

Depends on your definition of Rogue Planet. If any planet equipped with Hyperdrive capabilities, then **YES**.

From [Pablo Hidalgo's Twitter](https://twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/683418491802664960):

> The Starkiller is mobile. **Able to travel distances in hyperspace** amid a very populous star cluster.